# Running a psql command inside a Postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I'm open to other suggestions on how to do this. The goal is that when I commit my code to the repo and push to Prod it will run all my "create or replace" against my production DB.

I've written a release script that runs `run_all_procedures()` and inside that function, I want to have a bunch of commands that will run a bunch of other functions. So I guess I want to do something like this:

```
 Create Or Replace Function run_all_procedures() Returns void As $$ 
 Begin
    psql -f my_dir/do_something.sql
    psql -f my_dir/do_something_else.sql
    psql -f my_dir/do_a_final_thing.sql         
 End;
 $$ language plpgsql;
```

Of course, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Start to run this simple test as **superuser**:

```
  Create table cmd_result (str text); 

  Create Or Replace Function run_all_procedures() Returns void As $$ 
     Begin
     copy cmd_result from program 'psql postgres -c "select * from pg_stat_activity;" ';    
     End;
   $$ language plpgsql;

  select run_all_procedures();
  select * from cmd_result;
```

Maybe you will need to specify full path to get results from psql...

Now the function...

You must guarantee that postgres unix/windows-user have permission to read do_something.sql then just do:

```
 create table cmd_result (str text); 

 Create Or Replace Function run_all_procedures() Returns void As $$ 
 Begin
    copy cmd_result from program 'psql  -f /fullpath/do_something.sql" ';
    copy cmd_result from program 'psql  -f /fullpath/do_something_else.sql" ';
    copy cmd_result from program 'psql  -f /fullpath/do_a_final_thing.sql  " ';

 End;
 $$ language plpgsql;
```

And before calling the function create the temporary table results...

```
select run_all_procedures(); 
select * from cmd_result;
```

Please use fullpath (starting with /) instead of mydir, because postgresql will run the commands in the database directory. If u are in doubt about what i mean try:

```
   create table cmd_result(str text); 
   copy cmd_result from program '/bin/ls';
   select * from cmd_result;
```

That's all. ** Please select as the correct answer if solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Luciano. I'm working on this now. Just curious, is there no way to just run the psql command directly in the procedure? Meaning that if I `select run_all_procedures();` the function would simply run `psql  -f /fullpath/do_something.sql`?

Comment: Well the function will run the command....  You can create a temporary table inside the function code if you dont like to create the table outside.

Comment: @Lee let me know, is that right ? Can you mark my answer as the correct answer?

Comment: Great answer @LucianoAndressMartini ! Works fine on Postgres 14.